# (A) -> B to Kotlin Function not inferred

Tags: kotlin

I have two functions; one compiles and one does not

```
// compiles just fine
fun <A, B> CompletableFuture<A>.map(fn: (A) -> B): CompletableFuture<B> = 
    this.thenApplyAsync(fn)

// Compile error:
// Type inference failed: fun <U : Any!> thenApplyAsync(p0: Function<in A!, out U!>!, p1: Executor!): CompletableFuture<U!>!
// cannot be applied to
// ((A) -> B,ExecutorService)
// 
// Type mismatch: inferred type is (A) -> B but Function<in A!, out B!>! was expected
fun <A, B> CompletableFuture<A>.map(fn: (A) -> B): CompletableFuture<B> =
    this.thenApplyAsync(fn, BackgroundPool)
```

Why does the first function compile, but the second one does not?  Intellij's suggestion is to reimplement thenApplyAsync to be more kotlin friendly, but I am curious what the limitation is.

I am using kotlin 1.3.61

Answer (score 1):

Intellij IDEA says that there 4 available versions of `thenApplyAsync` which accepts:

1. `fn: Function<in A!, out B!>!`
2. `fn: Function<in A!, out B!>!, executor: Executor!`
3. `fn: ((A!) -> B!)!`
4. `fn: ((A!) -> B!)!, executor: ((Runnable!) -> Unit)!`

Besides originals (1) and (2), there are (3) and (4) which accept Kotlin functions instead of SAM interfaces. But there is no overloading which accepts one Kotlin function and one SAM interface: `fn: ((A!) -> B!), !executor: Executor!`. So your second method doesn't compile.

Here is how you can make it compile:

```
inline fun <A, B> CompletableFuture<A>.map(crossinline fn: (A) -> B): CompletableFuture<B> =
    this.thenApplyAsync(Function { fn(it) }, BackgroundPool)
```

Comment: Based off your feedback this is possible as well; tested it out and compiles just fine.

fun <A, B> CompletableFuture <A>.map(fn: (A) -> B): CompletableFuture <B> =
        this.thenApplyAsync(fn, BackgroundPool::execute)

Comment: Looking at the bytecode it looks like this gets boiled down to

Method AsyncKt$sam$java_util_function_Function$0."<init>":(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)V

Looking at the bytecode it looks like this creates a wrapper to convert to java function; so there will always be an extra indirection.